# Executing a jar file in bash script

Tags: bash

i want to write a bash script to execute a jar file.

The thing is i can't just write java -jar filename.jar cause it's gonna have several versions like :

filename-v1.0.jar

filename-v1.5.jar

filename-v2.0.jar

but i dont wanna have to chance the script. Is there a way to just write something like java -jar filename$.jar or something ??

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: And explain how is your script meant to know which file you actually want to run.

Answer (score 0):

First of all see if your IDE options can help you.

One option can be to have a version file in same directory. This file will include the version number and you can change it when you want. Then your command will be the next :

```
java -jar filename`cat version`.jar
```

This is an easy option. Then you can control your execution version only changing the content from this file.

If you looks for a pattern do something like :

```
java -jar `ls | grep "pattern"`
```

All your files reported by this command will be executed by java.

Comment: can't i just use something like a autocompletion in the terminal ? I mean im sure the file will be something like "123" and all the other files will be "abc"

Comment: Your bash script will be an independent process, you can make it ask version, or you can pass version over param but will not "autocomplete" without a specification.

Comment: what you can do is to find with a pattern, if you know which pattern will have execute the next command :

    java -jar `ls | grep "123"`

all your files containing "123" will be executed by java.

Answer (score 0):

inside bash script  use $1

java -jar $1

and then pass the jar name as argument to your script.

sh runjar.sh filename.jar
~

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar $1 // or filename-$1.jar or $1.jar
```

and then give it as argument like

```
myscript.sh filename-v1.0.jar // or v1.0 or filename-v1.0
```